# How to implement both scalar and vector addition using the += operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, vector-graphics

I'm working on a Vector2D class, and I think both vector addition and scalar addition make sense to be implemented with the +=/+ operators.

Trouble is, I don't really know how to work around this apparent argument ambiguity, here's what Clang says:

```
vector2d_test.cpp:17:16: error: use of overloaded operator
      '+=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Vector2D<float>' and 'int')
        vector += 1;
        ~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
vector2d.hpp:34:18: note: candidate function
    Vector2D<T>& operator+=(const Vector2D<T>& other)
                 ^
vector2d.hpp:41:18: note: candidate function
    Vector2D<T>& operator+=(const T summand) const
```

Here are the two functions:

```
Vector2D<T>& operator+=(const Vector2D<T>& other)
{
    x += other.x;
    y += other.y;
    return *this;
}

template <typename S>
Vector2D<T>& operator+=(const S summand) const
{
    x += summand;
    y += summand;
    return *this;
}
```

So... any idea what I can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.  The `operator+=`
functions you post aren't legal unless they are members.  And if
they are members, and you have something like:

```
Vector2D<float> v;
//   ...
v += 1;
```

the `Vector2D<float>::operator+=( Vector2D<float> const& )`
function isn't callable, and so there can be no ambiguity.  If
the functions aren't members, then they should be written:

```
template <typename T>
Vector2D<T>& operator+=( Vector2D<T>& lhs, Vector2D<T> const& rhs );
template <typename T, typename U>
Vector2D<T>& operator+=( Vector2D<T>& lhs, U rhs );
```

Even in this case, the first cannot be called with an `rhs` of
type `int`, so there is no ambiguity.

EDIT:

I missed the `const` at the end of the second in your posting.
This is an obvious typo on your part,  It still doesn't change
anything, *unless* you also have some implicit conversions to
`Vector2D` (which is probably not a good idea); otherwise, the
first version is still not callable.  If there is, for example,
an implicit conversion from `int` to `Vector2D`, and you call
`+=` on a non-const Vector2D, then the first overload is
a better match for the implicit first argument (which results in
the `this` pointer), since it is an exact match, without even
a cv conversion, but the second function is a better match for
the second argument, because the template instantiation results
in an exact match.  So the call is ambiguous.

Comment: The  ambiguity must arise from a constructor of `Vector2D<T>` taking an `int`. One also observes the erroneous `const` on the second member, leading us to conclude that this is definitely not enough code.

Comment: @DeadMG The spurious `const` is so obviously wrong that I overlooked it.  An `operator+=` should _never_ be `const`.  As I point out in my edit, however, you still need an implicit conversion for the call to be ambiguous.

Comment: Whoops, that const was actually the issue :P

Comment: @futlib Even with the `const`, overload resolution should work unless you have undesirable implicit conversions.  Consider making your constructors `explicit`.

Answer (score 2):

You have all written in you error message. You tried to add to your vector variable of int type, but your vector has floats. It should be:

```
vector += 1f;
```

or

```
vector += 1.0;
```

Take a look. When you have this vector:

```
Vector2D<float> vector;
```

function corresponding to this vector has header:

```
Vector2D<T>& operator+=(const float summand) const;
```

Second one doesn't matter right now. And when you try to add to your vector 1, you are trying to invoke function:

```
Vector2D<T>& operator+=(const int summand) const;
```

Which you didn't declare. That's why compiler message you an error - it can't find proper function.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to define the functions inside Vector2D ala:

```
Vector2D& operator+=(const Vector2D& rhs)
    { ...each this element += rhs's corresponding element... }

Vector2D& operator+=(const T& summand)
    { ...each this elements += summand... }

friend Vector2D operator+(Vector2D lhs, const Vector2D& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }

friend Vector2D operator+(Vector2D lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }
```

Notes:

- the non-member functions are `friend`s, which allows them to be defined conveniently inline
- the functions shouldn't be `const` (one was in your question)
- usual conversions will be attempted, so if `T` is `float` then `int`s will work just fine unless you do something funny like give `Vector2D` an implicit constructor from a single `int` that makes the choice of conversion ambiguous

Comment: @juanchopanza As he said, you define it (or at least declare it) inside the class, so it has an implicit first parameter of the class type.

Comment: @JamesKanze before the edit, it said "define the functions as friends inside Vector2D...".

Comment: @juanchopanza: yeah - sorry for the confusion... forgot to list the friend ones the first time around....