# How to create operator*(double) for multiplying on both the left and right hand side?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to figure out how to write an overloaded operator for my Vector2d class that allows me to multiply by a scalar on both the left and right sides.

```
class Vector2d
{
    double _x;
    double _y;

public:
    Vector2d(double x = 0, double y = 0) :_x(x), _y(y) {}

    Vector2d operator*(const double s) const
        { return Vector2d(_x * s, _y * s); }

    friend Vector2d operator*(const double s, const Vector2d& v);
};

Vector2d operator*(const double s, const Vector2d& v)
{
    return Vector2d(v._x * s, v._y * s);
}
```

If I only define the member operator*, my object can be multiplied on the right by a scalar but not the left.  If I add the friend function operator*, I get an error when I compile:

```
Vector2D.h:61: multiple definition of `Gf::operator*(double, Gf::Vector2d const&)'
Vector2D.h:61: first defined here
Vector2D.h:61: multiple definition of `Gf::operator*(double, Gf::Vector2d const&)'
```

What's the right way to do this?

---

I was putting the operator* function in the header file.  Once I moved it to the .cpp, it compiled correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement both scalar and vector addition using the += operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428854/how-to-implement-both-scalar-and-vector-addition-using-the-operator).  The link overloads a different operator,but the principle is the same.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're including that header in multiple places? Running that same code in its own .cpp file will work.

Comment: That was it. I was putting the operator* function in the header.

Comment: *"I was putting the operator\* function in the header file..."* - Leave the overloaded operator in the header, but make it `inline`. Write it so the overload calls into a member function through `const Vector2d& v`. That is, return `v.Multiply(s)` or similar. (The answer you accepted is questionable and likely suffers the same problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your file has been included multiple times, most compilers support [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) these days. You can also use a header guard (check for a token's definition before defining it along with the rest of your header) :

```
#ifndef VECTOR_2D
#define VECTOR_2D

class Vector2d
{
    double _x;
    double _y;

public:
    Vector2d(double x = 0, double y = 0) :_x(x), _y(y) {}

    Vector2d operator*(const double s) const
        { return Vector2d(_x * s, _y * s); }

    friend Vector2d operator*(const double s, const Vector2d& v);
};

Vector2d operator*(const double s, const Vector2d& v)
{
    return Vector2d(v._x * s, v._y * s);
}

#endif // VECTOR_2D
```

Comment: Given that the function causes an error and the class definition does not, I suspect the error is during linking, not compilation.  Header guard macros and pragma once won't do a thing to prevent definitions in multiple compilation units.